# Dialog Box displaying Blank despite having text in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My dialog is displaying without the info see image: My code is below.. I truly have no idea why . Any help will be appreciated

This is my code why is it displaying like this?

```
public class myDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

   @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder theDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        theDialog.setTitle("Settings");
        theDialog.setMessage("Use the Levels Button To choose Level");
        theDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );

        theDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    }


}
```

and on my main this is how i have passed it.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            DialogFragment myFragment = new DialogFragment();
            myFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"theDialog");



            return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the  DialogFragment class should be called from a FragmentActivity or a Fragment.

The class should be more like this :

```
public class DFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogfragment, container,
            false);
    getDialog().setTitle("DialogFragment Tutorial");        
    // Do something else
    return rootView;
}
 }
```

This is the activity that you call it from

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

Button dfragbutton;
Button alertdfragbutton;
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
    dfragbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dfragbutton);
    alertdfragbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alertdfragbutton);

    // Capture button clicks
    dfragbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            DFragment dFragment = new DFragment();
            // Show DialogFragment
            dFragment.show(fm, "Dialog Fragment");
        }
    });

    // Capture button clicks
    alertdfragbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            AlertDFragment alertdFragment = new AlertDFragment();
            // Show Alert DialogFragment
            alertdFragment.show(fm, "Alert Dialog Fragment");
        }
    });
}
 }
```

For more information please refer to : http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-dialogfragment-tutorial/

**If you need any more assistance I am more than ready to help**

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but i have seen some tutorial which perform the action albeit not extending the fragmentactivity in the main?

Comment: Referring to this :showing the dialog in an Activity (extending FragmentActivity or AppCompatActivity): from this link : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-DialogFragment. So you are right

Comment: Hey :) the code didnt solve my problem but the links did and i appreciate. :)

Comment: @MadonahSyombua anytime. Glad I could help. Happy coding